# Vue js with Laravel - login form security

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have simple app in Vue js, which pick between two forms - login with sms or password.

Is the application below safe?

Form with password login:

```
<template>
 <div v-if="status !== 265" class="loginForm">
    <label for="phone" class="">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="fields.phone">
    <input type="hidden" id="phone" name="phone" v-model="fields.phone">
    <div v-if="errors && errors.phone" class="text-danger">
       <p v-for="item in errors.phone">{{ item }}</p>
    </div>

      ---> same with password
    <input  type="submit" class="" value="Submit">
 </div>
 <div v-else>
     <!-- redirect to dashboard -->
 </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    mixins: [ FormMixin ],

    data() {
        return {
            fields: {},
            errors: {},
            success: false,
            loaded: true,
            status: 0,
            'action': '/klient/customer/login-authorization-password',
        }
    },

    methods: {
        submit() {
            if (this.loaded) {
                this.loaded = false;
                this.success = false;
                this.errors = {};

                axios.post(this.action, this.fields).then(response => {
                    this.fields = {};
                    this.loaded = true;
                    this.success = true;
                    this.status = response.status;;
                }).catch(error => {
                    this.loaded = true;
                    if (error.response.status === 422) {
                        this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
                    }
                });
            }
        },

    },
}
</script>
```

Controller in PHP:

```
public function loginAuthorizationPassword(Request $request) {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'phone' => 'required|numeric',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);

        $customer = \DB::connection('mysql2')
            ->table('customer')
            ->where('phone_login', $request['phone'])
            ->where('password', NULL)
            ->first();

        if(!$customer) return response()->json(null, 265); //wrong password or customer no exist


        if ($customer->password != NULL && Hash::check($request['password'], $customer->password)) {
            Session::set('loggedIn', TRUE);
            Session::set('id', $customer->id);
            return response()->json(null, 267); //return user is valid
        } else return response()->json(null, 265); //wrong password or customer no exist
    }
```

After response with status 267, vue redirect to /customer/dashboard and PHP check session variable loggedIn. If loggedIn is true, user have access to data with their id.

Comment: You have to use a package like [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#introduction), you do not have to store in session like `Session::set('loggedIn', true);` (please, never use `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `NULL`, read about PSR). If you do not use a package like that, you are going to mess up a lot of things related to authentication and authorization that Laravel has built-in. Read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#introduction) about it.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I will change it. I mean the security of the data transmission from vue form to php controller. And if data will be valid, controller return status code, vue redirect to dashboard and controller will check if user is login with Laravel Sanctum. I don't program in vue but I need it for my implementation of login form.

Comment: If data is sent over HTTPS is secure. I would not use custom http status codes. Better return a standard status codes (403 maybe?), and return a message or code in the body: `->json (['message'=>'dashboard'], 403)`

Comment: @MaartenVeerman I return code between 200-300, because vue does not consider it as error. I know that this app is very primitive but if it's safe that's enough for me. I'll do the rest in php. Thank you!